# Random function and calculating percentage

Tags: math, random

Using a random library with these functions:

`randomChance(p)    Returns true with the probability indicated by p.`

`randomInteger(low, high)  Returns a random integer in the range low to high, inclusive.`

what is the easiest way to implement a "random selector" that takes consideration of percentage, 1/4 or 1/3 etc... I got a array with key/value pairing. For example `"a"` migth have the value 2 and `"b"` have the value 2. 1/2 chance for both.

The max value will be the size of the array, cause it only contains unique items. The `randomChance()` function ranges between `0.0 - 1.0` where 1 = 100%. If my array size is, say 4. What is the best way of "letting 4 be 1".

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What is this "1/4 or 1/3 etc" percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have:

```
a = 2, b = 2, c = 1, d = 3
```

now make it:

```
a = 2, b = 4, c = 5, d = 8
```

Create a random number from 1 to MaxVal (value of the last key, 8 in this example). Select the first Key where Value >= RandomNum

**EDIT**

I made a small VB.Net to show the algorithm and how it works. The code is not meant to be: Good, elegant, performant or readable.

```
Module Module1

    Private Class Value
        Public vOrg, vRecalc, HitCount As Integer
        Public Key As String
        Public Sub New(s, v1, v2, c)
            Key = s : vOrg = v1 : vRecalc = v2 : HitCount = c
        End Sub
    End Class

    Sub Main()

        ' set initial values
        Dim KVP() As Value = {New Value("A", 2, 0, 0),
                              New Value("B", 2, 0, 0),
                              New Value("C", 1, 0, 0),
                              New Value("D", 3, 0, 0)}
        ' recalc values
        For i = 0 To KVP.Length - 1
            If i = 0 Then KVP(0).vRecalc = KVP(0).vOrg Else KVP(i).vRecalc = KVP(i).vOrg + KVP(i - 1).vRecalc
        Next
        ' do test
        Dim r As New Random
        Dim runs As Integer = 1000 * 1000, maxval As Integer = KVP(KVP.Length - 1).vRecalc
        For i = 1 To runs
            Dim RandVal = r.Next(1, maxval + 1)
            Dim chosen As Integer = (From j In Enumerable.Range(0, KVP.Length) Where KVP(j).vRecalc >= RandVal Take 1 Select j)(0)
            KVP(chosen).HitCount += 1
        Next
        ' ouput results
        For Each kv In KVP
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was chosen with {1:F3} propability, expected was {2:F3}", kv.Key, kv.HitCount / CDbl(runs), kv.vOrg / CDbl(maxval))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

An output sample:

```
A was chosen with 0.250 propability, expected was 0.250
B was chosen with 0.251 propability, expected was 0.250
C was chosen with 0.124 propability, expected was 0.125
D was chosen with 0.375 propability, expected was 0.375
```

Comment: That´s simple and little code, I like it. But for maxVal, if I am correct, that would have to be the sum of all values a,b,c,d (2+2+1+3) Am I correct, my math skill are embarassing lol?

Comment: MaxVal is the the Value of the last key (after recalculation)

Comment: @igrimpe: your solution is completely wrong: the "c" will be picked with probability 4/8 which is wrong (it should be 1/8)

Comment: c is picked exactly and only when RandomVal is 5. Because it is the first Key where Val >= RandomVal is true. Therefore c is picked 1/8.

Comment: @G_G: I'va added some sample code. Still believing that the algorithm is wrong?

Comment: @igrimpe: eventually you defined (on your code) the "Select the first Key" statement as "the key with the lower array index" and that's all I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 1):

just multiply the randomChance() outcome and the array length together. It'll give you the index in the range [0,array_length-1] which you can use to access the array

```
array_index = (unsigned int)(randomChance(p) * (array_length - 1));
```

maybe you mean "letting 3 to be 1" (not 4) in your example. The last index of an array of length 4 is 3.

Comment: Good solution, but works only for equally distributed keys (same chance for each key). And of course you could simple create a random number from 0 to maxindex.

Comment: making it non-uniform is just a matter of repeating multiple times the values across the array or making the randomChange() itself a non-uniform function

Comment: `repeating multiple` - me not liketh redundancy ;)